# How to open the side navigation drawer when click on bottom menu?

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview

This is what i'm trying to achieve

I want settings menu click will appear side nav drawer

[image]

HomeActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    mMainFrame  =   (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    mMainNav    =   (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);

    homeFragment         =   new HomeFragment();
    analyticsFragment    =   new AnalyticsFragment();
    paymentFragment      =   new PaymentFragment();
    settingsFragment     =   new SettingsFragment();

    drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,new HomeFragment()).commit();

    mMainNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    setFragment(homeFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_analytics:
                    setFragment(analyticsFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_payment:
                    setFragment(paymentFragment);
                    return true;

                case R.id.navigation_settings:
                    drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });

    BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
    navView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

And this is the error i get

```
Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ewallet/com.example.ewallet.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.app.Activity.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

EDIT : I tried to paste some of my code here but StackOverflow error too many code to post

Answer (score 0):

You didn't bind your object correctly and caused a NullPointerException.

Please paste your code and we can help you.

I saw a weird part, but maybe this error will still appear, you may need to paste your layout.xml

```
mMainNav    =   (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.main_nav);


BottomNavigationView navView = findViewById(R.id.main_nav);
navView.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

Should be modify to

```
mMainNav.setItemIconTintList(null);
```

You can check if it is null with

```
getActivity().findViewById(R.id.XXX)
```

UPDATE

```
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout)getView().findViewById(R.id.drawerlayout);

    case R.id.navigation_settings:
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerLayout);
                return true;
```

Comment: Yes i got blocked by SO for too many code. Now i managed to edited some. Please check it out thanks!

Comment: I dont think that is the problem. mMainNav is for btmnav to control fragment above it. What i want is to click one of the btmnav menu to display side navdrawer which is drawerlayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END) returned null error.

Comment: Cannot resolve method 'getView()' sir. I also tried with getActivity() as other answered question but still cannot resolve method

Answer (score 0):

Took me 4 days to figure this out. Turned out you need to have drawerlayout in your activity layout. My problem was drawerlayout from different xml that's why returned null. Thx for those who tried for helping me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="end">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_settings"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_settings"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_settings_drawer" />

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="56dp">

    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/main_nav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```